# Difference between MORAN I and LISA

Tags: autocorrelation, moran-index

i'm trying to define what is the main difference between [Moran I](https://www.statisticshowto.com/morans-i/) and [LISA](http://geodacenter.github.io/workbook/6a_local_auto/lab6a.html) (local indicator of spatial autocorrelation,which is, as far as I understand,local Moran).
I know te MORAN I is global and LISA is local, but I find it hard to understand what is the difference as seems like both check autocorrelation with the sorround.

I'm looking for good -**simple explaination**, that will give me t**he sense of that difference**, because now I'm reading again and again but can't understand the actual difference.

Comment: I agree with you that local Moran is the same as LISA (LISA is the broader concept). Local Moran is an implementation of Moran's I for each location (observation). In other words, Moran's I is in a sense the average of Local Moran over the region.